# How to get first and last record in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create previous and next record hyperlink in my page. The complete record has to be displayed. I am very well doing this, but after reaching the first record or last record if the previous or last links are getting pressed it giving me error. How to resolve this. TIA. my code is

```
$prevquery= "SELECT * FROM SKU_det WHERE bi_SKU < $SKU ORDER BY bi_SKU DESC LIMIT 1"; 
    $prevresult = mysql_query($prevquery) or die(mysql_error());
    while($prevrow = mysql_fetch_array($prevresult))
    {
    $previd  = $prevrow['bi_SKU'];
    }


$nextquery= "SELECT * FROM SKU_det WHERE bi_SKU> $SKU ORDER BY bi_SKU ASC LIMIT 1"; 
$nextresult = mysql_query($nextquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($nextrow = mysql_fetch_array($nextresult))
{
$nextid  = $nextrow['bi_SKU'];
}
echo $SKU;
if ($SKU==0){
    echo "<strong> < Previous</a>";
    echo "<strong> Next ></a>";
}
else if($SKU<>0){
    echo "<a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=$previd'><strong> < Previous</a>";
    echo "<a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=$nextid'><strong> Next ></a>";
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you code in a better way, i've made some changes, because if you continue working on the example wlalele gave, you will soon have problems with Mysql injection and deprecated mysql functions.

```
if (isset($SKU)){ //check if SKU is set before creating query.
   $prevquery= "SELECT bi_SKU FROM SKU_det WHERE bi_SKU < '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SKU). "' ORDER BY bi_SKU DESC LIMIT 1";  //escape external input
    $prevresult = mysqli_query($prevquery) or die(mysqli_error());
    if ($prevresult && mysqli_num_rows($prevquery)){ // check if there is a result
        $prevrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prevresult))  { // you are requesting 1 record, no need for while loop, also assoc array because you dont need array
        $previd  = $prevrow['bi_SKU'];
    }
    $nextquery= "SELECT bi_SKU FROM SKU_det WHERE bi_SKU > '" . mysql_real_escape_string($SKU). "' ORDER BY bi_SKU DESC LIMIT 1"; 
    $nextresult = mysqli_query($nextquery) or die(mysqli_error());
    if ($nextresult && mysqli_num_rows($nextresult)){ // check if there is a result
        $nextrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nextresult))  { // you are requesting 1 record, no need for while loop, also assoc array because you dont need array
        $nextid  = $nextrow['bi_SKU'];
    }
    echo htmlSpecialChars($SKU); //make sure to escape external input
    if (!isset($previd)){
    //only if a previd exists, show button
     echo '<a href="CopyAdd.php?SKU='.$previd.'"><strong> &lt; Previous</strong></a>'; //corrected your html
    }
    if (!isset($nextid)){
    //only if a nextid exists, show button
     echo '<a href="CopyAdd.php?SKU='.$nextid.'"><strong> Next &gt;</strong></a>'; //corrected your html
    }
} else {
    echo 'No SKU set';
    //make a query to fetch first SKU and only show NEXT > for example.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Garytje... it's working just the way I wanted.

Comment: You are welcome,  please mark my answer as the correct one, as someone that comes by won't copy the wrong kind of code..

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if you have a $previd (or $nextid)
If you dont have one, just hide the prev (or next) link

```
$prevquery= "SELECT * FROM SKU_det WHERE bi_SKU < $SKU ORDER BY bi_SKU DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$prevresult = mysql_query($prevquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($prevrow = mysql_fetch_array($prevresult))
{
  $previd = null;
  if (array_key_exist('bi_SKU', $prevrow) && is_int($prevrow['bi_SKU'])) {
    $previd  = $prevrow['bi_SKU'];
  }
}

$nextquery= "SELECT * FROM SKU_det WHERE bi_SKU> $SKU ORDER BY bi_SKU ASC LIMIT 1"; 
$nextresult = mysql_query($nextquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($nextrow = mysql_fetch_array($nextresult))
{
  $nextid = null;
  if (array_key_exist('bi_SKU', $nextrow) && is_int($nextrow['bi_SKU'])) {
    $nextid  = $nextrow['bi_SKU'];  
  }
}
echo $SKU;
if ($SKU==0){
    echo "<strong> < Previous</a>";
    echo "<strong> Next ></a>";
}
else if($SKU<>0){
    if ($previd !== null) {
        echo "<a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=$previd'><strong> < Previous</a>";
    }
    if ($nextid !== null) {
        echo "<a href='CopyAdd.php?SKU=$nextid'><strong> Next ></a>";
    }
}`
```